# Remove mouse hover effect from angular calendar's tr/ td

Tags: css, calendar

I have wrote a table style which changes tr/td's bg color when mouse over. I want to remove this bg color change for my "Angular calendar" - Since it has been built by using tables, whenever I mouse over a day/week/month I am getting this mouse over effect too - I would like to remove it. Please help..

CSS:

```
td.red, td.red:hover { 
    background-color:#FFC7CE;
}

table:hover > tbody > tr:hover > td.red { 
    background:#FFC7CE; 
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 4px 2px -3px #FFC7CE inset;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 4px 2px -3px #FFC7CE inset;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 2px -3px #FFC7CE inset;
} 

table:hover > tbody > tr:hover > td, table:hover > tbody > tr:hover > th {
    background-color: #fafafa;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to make a new class for your "Angular calendar". Then use the `!important` tag to override the other formatting.

Like so:

```
.angularCalendarClass:hover {
    background: /*desired format */ !important; 
    -moz-box-shadow: /*desired format */ !important;
    -webkit-box-shadow: /*desired format */ !important;
    box-shadow: /*desired format */ !important;
}
```